# Custom timeout for xna wp7 Webclient

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

Since there is no timeout for responce in windows phone xna version of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) i need to implement one. The idea is to make `MyWebClient` derived class from `WebClient` with timer. But i got stuck on it.
Is there any way to implement timer here without using `Update` for every instance of `MyWebClient` so that i can use it like `WebClient`?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) ? You could start the timer with your timeout a Interval value and register a tick event. When the event fires you throw a exception for a timeout (or do whatever pleases you).
You could even hook up the DownloadProgressChanged event of the webclient and reset the timer or smth. like this.

Comment: Cannot figure out how to use it. I catch `Invalid cross-thread access.` when create instance of `DispatcherTimer`

Comment: Try using a normaler timer then, the dispatcher timer is tied to the dispatcher thread (UI-Thread)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using static varible `TotalGameTime` in main game `Update`

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            TotalGameTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
```

And then in `MyWebClient` save start state of `TotalGameTime` and compare with current gameTime

```
while (currentGameTime - startGameTime < timeout)
                    {
                       //
                    currentGameTime = Game1.TotalGameTime;                            
                    }
```

I dont find this solution clean but anyway it solves the problem.